# Cleanest way to get a File in a JUnit test case from Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, junit

My test code in Maven project B (which is a child of project A) has something like

```
String filePath = "src/main/webapp";
//do something with the filePath
```

The above test case runs fine when I run the project from child (i.e, level B) but when I run from Parent project A (i.e, doing a mvn install at parent level) this fails because obviously there is no folder called "src/main/webapp" under parent level (It is however available in child level).

I know I could do some coding do check if a test case is running from parent/child module but apparently I want to know what *others* have done when they have had this problem ?

And no, I cant use the classpath instead (for various boring reasons).

I also tried relative path but then the test case sort of starts to know too much. Is there actually a solution at all for this ?

**UPDATE (12/Feb)** - I have a web.xml under webapp folder and create a jetty server in a test case using that web.xml. Ideally src/main/webapp is not placed in the classpath. It is used by the WAR plugin to package the WAR. Now, I tried an alternative where I put my web.xml in the src/main/resource/console-webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml directory and altered the webXml attribute in the maven war plugin. This seems to solve my problem. However, in the output WAR I have a web.xml and another redundant web.xml (which was copied because it is in the classpath).

I have tried "packageExcludes" and "webResources/excludes" and got the war plugin to omit the second web.xml but still the directory "console-webapp" gets copied (although is empty). Is there any way to tell maven war plugin to ignore a directory completely (i.e, what is the ant pattern for that?)

Comment: Maven 2 tests are run in the module directory in a separate process. This means that "src/main/webapp" should work perfectly well no matter from where it was invoked. Are you testing with surefire plugin? JUnit / TestNG? Did you disable forking for surefire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Maven 2 conventions state that all test resources, including files such as the one you are trying to use in your test, must be stored in the `src/test/resources` folder. If you respect this convention, you will be able to get your file from the classpath directly. These resources will **not** be included in the final packaging (JAR, WAR, EAR...).

Of course, you can change the directory and then specify the new test resources directory in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>...</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    ...
```

In your question, you specified that you can't use the classpath. Why so?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that by convention all test resources should go into src/test/resources.

Comment: The above is true but the OP is very likely not trying to load a test resource but a file from the webapp.

Comment: Pascal you are right. I have updated the question with some details from my findings. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the file you are trying to access on the test classpath?  If so, how about:

```
public class IOUtils {

  public URL getResourceAsURL(String resource) {
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
    return cl.getResource(resource);
  }


  public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) throws IOException  {
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream(resource);

    if (in == null) 
      throw new IOException("resource \"" + resource + "\" not found");

    return in;
  }
}
```